# How Can You Bind a List<String> to a StackPanel

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8

In my application I have a `List` of `string`s, however I can't find out how to/don't know how to bind this list to a `StackPanel`.

I've tried using a `ListBox` but the scrolling nature of the `ListBox` is very inconvenient to the user of my application.

So does anyone know how I could bind a `List` of `string`s to a `StackPanel`?

I have tried messing around with several properties but haven't found anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? I am quite sure that there are a ton of examples out there on the internet. Please do some research and show effort opposed to expecting others to give you the answer and or do your work  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To bind an enumerable to a control and have them displayed, you can use any of the [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) and bind your object to the `ItemsSource` property. The `ItemsControl`s expose a property called [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) in which you can further modify to alter the container for the items. `StackPanel` is the default in most of them.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NewbieList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- The default for an ItemsControl is a StackPanel with a vertical orientation -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Edit:**

As for your comment, anything within the `ItemsSource` will "output" what's in the `ItemTemplate` property (the default is basicaly a `TextBlock` with the text bound to the `DataContext`). For each elements, the `DataContext` will be the item in the list. If you have a list of  `string`, for example, you can do:

```
<!-- Rest is omitted for succinctness -->
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="26" MouseDown="yourEventHandler"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl>
```

Alternatively, if all you want is the font size to change, you can use the `TextElement.FontSize` Dependency Property on the `ItemsControl` itself or style the `ItemsContainer`:

```
<ItemsControl TextElement.FontSize="26">
    <!-- Rest omitted for succinctness -->
</ItemsControl>
```

Or:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="26"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I suggest you read articles / tutorials on binding and items control in WPF for more information on how to do various tasks, there is alot to explain.

Comment: That almost works, but I need to be able to retrieve a click event for each individual item in the template, and I don't seem to be able to do that with the StackPanel

Comment: @Newbie See my edit. You should definitely read some tutorials on WPF for more information on bindings, data templates and items control.

Comment: Yeah I tried just using a `TextBlock` but that brought up an UnhandledException, sorry that you went to all the trouble of answering my deleted comment, I figured that out by just adding `FontSize="32"` under the `Items.Control`.