# How to binding UserControl in a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My question is simple, can I use binding in a StackPanel from elements in a LinkedList?
In my application the order of the elements in the LinkedList is importante. May the elements can change its positions in the LinkedList on the fly. I want to know if its possible to bind my LinkedList so my app always displays the elements in the correct order without any additional C# code/Event triggers.

Its possible to do this in WPF?

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? If so, where are you stuck, what are your issues with your solution?

Comment: `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyLinkedList }"/>`

Comment: `LinkedList<T>` implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` hence I'd assume that it would be possible to bind to and that the order would be maintained. There already is an answer on how to bind to a `StackPanel`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187784/how-can-you-bind-a-liststring-to-a-stackpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of an `ItemsControl` to your linked list:

```
ic.ItemsSource = yourList;
```

...and optionally define a custom `ItemsPanelTemplate` for the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```